# Spring data JPA - ConstraintViolationException on CrudRepository save()

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I've have a problem with Spring data JPA (with Hibernate, Postgre SQL and jdbc).
I have 2 entities, Texte and Annotation and 2 repositories, TexteRepository and AnnotationRepository that extend CrudRepository.
Annotation has a many to one relation with Texte. In a controller, I'm doing something like this :

```
Annotation annotation = new Annotation();
Texte texte = texteRepository.findOne(id);
if(texte != null) {
  annotation.setTexte(texte);
  annotationRepository.save(annotation);
}
```

While doing this, I've got a ConstraintViolationException :

```
could not execute statement; SQL [n/a]; constraint [id_texte]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement
```

What I understand is that Hibernate doesn't know that my texte entity is already persisted so it try to insert it. I come from .NET, but what I'd say is that texte is not "attached" to the same database context than annotation.

Here are my entities declarations (I show you only the relevant properties) :

```
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
public class Texte {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;
...
}

@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@Audited
public class Annotation {
       @Id
       @GeneratedValue
       private Long id;

       @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
       @Audited(targetAuditMode = RelationTargetAuditMode.NOT_AUDITED)
       private Texte texte;

    ...
}
```

Thank you very much

Clément

Answer (score 0):

Mapping of Texte is not proper in Annotation class, you need to define a column (i.e. foreign key) linking both tables

Comment: What do you mean ? All my relations in my model are declared like this, with ManyToOne, OneToOne, ManyToMany... If you don't specify a foreign column, it creates by itself a xxx_id column. In my case, I see a texte_id column in my database and a constraint between texte_id and the id column in the Text table.